# what is determinantal process?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Would anyone please explain what does this mean?

> A random point process $P$ on a discrete base set $Y =
> \{1,\ldots,N\}$ is a probability measure on the set $2^Y$ of all
>   subsets of $Y$. Let $K$ be a semidefinite matrix with rows
>   and columns indexed by the elements of $Y$. $P$ is called a
>   determinantal point process (DPP) if there exists some matrix $K$ with
>   all eigenvalues less than or equal to $1$, such that if $Z$ is a
>   random set drawn according to $P$, then for every $A ⊆ Y$:
>   $P(Z ⊇ A) = \det(K_A)$.

my problem is exactly this:
we know an of example of point process is poisson process,but how does it define a probability measure on Y?
and what does it mean: " Z is a random set drawn according to P."?

thanks!

Comment: What is $K_A$ ?

Comment: @zoli $K_A ≡ [K_{i,j}]$ for $i,j\in A$ denotes the restriction of $K$ to the entries indexed by elements of $A$,
and we adopt $det(K_∅) = 1$.

Comment: $\det A$=the product of the eigenvalues.

Comment: @zoli yes but  i can't understand how is P a probability measure

Comment: @user115608 I think you are looking at it backwards: a probability measure is called a DPP if there exists such a matrix which describes it. You are not necessarily guaranteed (at least from what you've already written) that all semidefinite matrices with eigenvalues at most 1 induce a probability measure this way. The more interesting question, I think, is what is *one* example of such a matrix. For that I think it is probably most natural to think about diagonal matrices. For instance, is there a multiple of the identity that induces such a matrix?

Comment: @lan my problem is exactly this:an of example of point process is poisson process,but how does it define a probability measure on $Y$?and what does it mean: " $Z$ is a random set drawn according to $P$."?

Comment: A reformulation of the text you quote (and giving the source would be a bonus) is that indeed $P$ is a probability measure on $2^Y$ and that $\det K_A$ is actually $P(\Omega_A)$ where $\Omega_A=\{\omega\in2^Y\mid\omega\supseteq Y\}$.

Comment: @Did:i'm reading this article,the text above is from :https://www.stat.washington.edu/~ebfox/publications/MDPP_UAI.pdf

Comment: OK. And is my previous comment answering your question?

Answer (score 0):

$P$ is a distribution over $2^Y$, the set of all subsets of $Y$. $P$ is just a discrete distribution that assigns a probability to each $Z\subseteq Y$. For a DPP, this discrete probability is defined in terms of a "marginal," in the sense that if you fix some $A\subseteq Y$, then you have a matrix $K_A$ that defines the probability of containing $A$:

$$
P(A\subseteq Z) \equiv \sum_{Z\supseteq A} P(Z) = \det(K_A)
$$

I agree that this definition is a bit lopsided. Perhaps someone else can motivate why this is a natural definition. I find that L-ensembles somewhat easier to get an intuition for. I highly recommend taking a look at Alex Kulesza and Ben Taskar's work on DPPs in machine learning. [This](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/papers/NIPS2010_0880) has a dense but good introduction and [this](http://www.alexkulesza.com/pubs/dpps_fnt12.pdf) is a great review of their work.

Answer (score 0):

The key idea of the given definition is as follows:
If $P$ is a DPP defined over a set $Y$, then if you draw a random subset $Z$ of $Y$, the probability of some elements(given by $A$) such that they appear in this sampled $Z$ is given by the corresponding minor of the determinant of kernel matrix $K$.

For example, consider the following illlustrative kernel matrix $K$ over three elements $\{1, 2, 3\}$
$$ K = 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13}\\
x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23}\\
x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33}\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

If $K$ represents the kernel matrix of DPP $P$ (assuming all required mathematical properties of positive definiteness and bounded spectrum), let say we sample a $Z$ of length 2, then the probability that set $A = \{1, 3\}$ is part of Z is given by the following determinant:

$$\Rightarrow
\left|
\begin{matrix}
x_{11} && x_{13} \\
x_{31} && x_{33}
\end{matrix}
\right|
$$

$$ 
\Rightarrow (x_{11}\cdot x_{33} - x_{13}\cdot x_{31})
$$